# how to check if item exists in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array like this

```
   var open_chats = [];
   open_chats.push({
    "chatid": 'dfsfsdfsdf',
    "data": 'adfsdf'
   });
```

I need to check if an item exists in this array, I am using something like this.

```
    if ($.inArray('dfsfsdfsdf', open_chats) !== -1){
    alert('contains');
    }
```

Except this does not seem to work. I cant quite find something that will work for this array. Can anyone help?

Comment: The elements of `open_chats` are objects, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is checking if `'dfsfsdfsdf'` is in the array, not if an object with a property of `chatid` has `'dfsfsdfsdf'` as its value.

Using native JavaScript array methods:

```
var hasMatch = open_chats.some(function(chat) {
    return chat.chatid === 'dfsfsdfsdf';
});
if (hasMatch) {
    alert('contains');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are having objects, not strings in your array I would suggest to use jQuery's [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) method:

```
var result = $.grep( open_chats, function( data ){ return data.chatid == 'dfsfsdfsdf'; });

if( result.length ) {
    alert('contains');
}
```

Comment: This works, but `$.grep` is going to build a new array containing all matches, whereas `Array.prototype.some` will loop through until one match is found and stop. If you don't need that result array, that's not the best option.

Comment: Yes, but `Array.prototype.some` not working in old IE browsers ( e.g < 9 )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some Lists a polyfill for `Array.prototype.some`